# Use ABCPDF to replace text in PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, abcpdf

I'm using ABC PDF and I was wondering if there is a way to load an existing template PDF, replace certain placeholders with actual values and then save to a new path?

I've been searching through their documentation, and I can find ways of getting text out of a Document (using Doc.GetText("Text")) but I can't find a way of setting the text back into the document.

Anyone out there know of a way to do this?

For instance, my PDF document contains placeholders like this:
"Hello [FIRSTNAME]", where I would like to replace [FIRSTNAME] with an actual name.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Also: if anyone knows of a way to do this without ABCPDF but with some other (free) library, that is also a good solution.

Edit: I have a DocX file which I can edit programmatically just fine, but I'm having trouble converting it to a PDF. So if you have a solution where I can convert my file easily, that will also do.

Comment: In general trying to replace text in PDF documents is not a good idea. What you should consider instead is adding form fields and filling them.

Comment: Okay. Can I add those form fields using Word and then save as PDF? Would that still work?

Comment: I would propose trying. In the back of my head I remember reading about some problems in certain situations but that would imply that it is possible in principle.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't seem to be working. I've found online that I can use Open Office to export my docx file to a PDF and keep the form fields intact, but that seems a no-go as well. Happen to have any experience with this?

Comment: No, I have only created form fields using Adobe Acrobat or (programmatically) certain PDF libraries yet.

Comment: Did you try this? 
http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/4-examples/15-eform1.htm